# Call jQuery function in a loop with different parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, carousel, jcarousel

I am trying to create multiple carousels in one page following [this](http://www.egrappler.com/jquery-contentthumbnail-slder-v2-0-jscarousel-v2-0/) example.
I am creating my carousels in a foreach loop, and I assign to each carousel the names c0, c1, c2, etc. (Each carousel is a `<div>`)
Now, in order to run the script according to the example, I should run in on each carousel separately.
For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#c0').jsCarousel({ onthumbnailclick: function(src) { alert(src); }, autoscroll: true, masked: false, itemstodisplay: 3, orientation: 'v' });
        $('#c1').jsCarousel({ onthumbnailclick: function(src) { alert(src); }, autoscroll: false, masked: false, itemstodisplay: 5, orientation: 'h' });
        $('#c2').jsCarousel({ onthumbnailclick: function(src) { alert(src); }, autoscroll: true, masked: true, itemstodisplay: 5, orientation: 'h' });

    });       

</script>
```

Since my carousels are created in a foreach loop, I cannot know how many of them I will have, so I tried to call the function in a for loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        string cNum = "#c" + i.ToString();%>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(cNum).jsCarousel({ onthumbnailclick: function(src) { alert(src); }, autoscroll: true });
            });
        </script>
   <%} %>
```

I checked, and the `cNum` values are okay, it gets the values #c0, #c1, etc. but it can't recognize it as an equivalent to '#c0' etc. that were there initially.

How can I insert dynamic carousel names into the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing that, just give each div a class. Like this:

```
<div class="someClassThatIKnowIsACarousel">
```

Then you don't need a loop:

```
$(".someClassThatIKnowIsACarousel").jsCarousel({ onthumbnailclick: function(src) { alert(src); }, autoscroll: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that `cNum` inside your dynamically generated JavaScript section isn't interpreted as an ASP variable. You could fix that with something like `$('<% cNum %>')` (also note the JavaScript quotes, without get you would get `$(#c0)`, which is erroneous).

However, your approach is wrong, please avoid the best you can mixing server/client code like that.

As aquinas already pointed out, the best solution is to add a class to the divs:

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel">
```

JavaScript:

```
$('div.carousel').jsCarousel({ ... });
```